# guard gem do not watch file changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard

I am using:

- rails 5.1.5
- guard 2.14.2
- linuxmint

Yesterday I installed guard, with the plugins **livereload** and **minitest**.

I use **guard** to automate my tests and make sure nothing gets broken by mistake.

I found out that for some reason, guard was not reacting to file changes. When it was first launched, it runned all tests, give me a prompt, and I had to press Enter in the prompt, and then, it start doing *ALL THE TESTS* ***again***, each round takes about 1hr.

Answer (score 0):

After googling and trying everything I found, nothing seemed to work. So, I cool down my horses, and decided to play with guard.

Problem found and solved.

**PROBLEM:** guard do not react (it is watching) on file changes

**THE CAUSE:** the regex that are used in Guardfile, seem to be incompatible with rails 5.1.5 file paths

**SOLUTION:**

```
guard :minitest do
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)_mailer/.+})  { |m| "test/mailers/#{m[1]}_mailer_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{^test/.+_test\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^test/test_helper\.rb$})     { 'test' }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.*)\.rb$}) { |m| "test/functional/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.*)\.rb$}) { |m| "test/controllers/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.*)\.rb$}) { |m| "test/integration/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/helpers/(.*)\.rb$})     { |m| "test/helpers/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/mailers/(.*)\.rb$})     { |m| "test/mailers/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/models/(.*)\.rb$})      { |m| "test/models/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/veiws/(.*)\.rb$})       { |m| "test/system/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
end
```

I hope this could be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I just fine tuned the regex. Here they come:

```
guard :minitest do
  watch(%r{test\/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{app\/controllers\/(.*)\.rb})       { |m| "test/controllers/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{app\/controllers\/(.*)\.rb})       { |m| "test/integration/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{app\/helpers\/(.*)\.rb})           { |m| "test/helpers/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{app\/models\/(.*)\.rb})            { |m| "test/models/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{app\/mailers\/(.*)\.rb})           { |m| "test/mailers/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{app\/views\/(.*)\/.*\.html\.haml}) { |m| "test/system/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
  watch(%r{app\/views\/(.*)\/.*\.coffee})     { |m| "test/system/#{m[1]}_test.rb" }
end
```